# continuous deployment with jenkins--need deployment script to deploy the build artifacts

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-scriptler

we are building java based code thru Jenkins and we are trying to deploy the build code thru Jenkins.can anyone provide deployment script which call s thru jenkins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deployment process varies depends on your application. Its difficult to provide a generic deployment script without knowing your deployment process.

In my opinion there are several plugins in Jenkins which can do deployment for you, if you don't have any deployment process exists yet I suggest you go through all available Jenkins deployment plugins and you can choose a good fit for your process.

Few available plugins are ..

```
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ArtifactDeployer+Plugin     
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Deploy+Plugin      
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Deploy+WebSphere+Plugin      
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Deployit+Plugin      
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/LiveRebel+Plugin
```

Comment: Thanks seidhar.PFB some info i have
The continuous build is done with Jenkins. The build generates 3 different artifacts: The war file A zip with layouts A zip with images So far, so good, but now I need to write the deploy script, which should: Deploy the war (artifact 1) to the jboss running at server 1 Place the artifact 2 at server 1 in a specific directory Place the artifact 3 at server 2 in a specific directory So I was talking with my colleague and he said that we should also generate an artifact (maybe deploy.xml) that deploys these artifacts when placed at the correct server.

Comment: So there would be another script, that would: Download the jenkins artifacts scp to each server and place the deploy.xml there remotely invoke the deploy.xml What makes me a little uncomfortable is the act of having the deploy.xml as a build artifact.

Comment: The motivation behind this would be to be able to make a deploy without needing to have access to the VCS repositories, so a build would be self-contained, ie, any build could go into production only with what was generated by Jenkins. Where should the deploy scripts be placed? Should they be only at the VCS or should they be build artifacts too?